# How do I boost up my android studio's emulator on mac?

Tags: android-studio

Android studio's emulator takes like ages to start and also crashes sometimes and at times does not show output, is very very slow.
OS X Yosemite
version 10.10.1

MacBook Pro (15-inc, late 2008)
Processor 2.4 GHz Intel core 2 Duo
Memory 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Startup Disk Untitled
Graphics NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT  256MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember correcly your MacBook do not support Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager becouse the cpu is quite old :-( (mine is too) so the default android emulator will be so so slow and there is no way to fix it

Yes you can tweek some parameters and maybe gain a second but it would be very marginal gain.

I use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is realy fast and run well on ald machines, give it a try. Is commercial product. It han the big disadvantage that there is no images with google play services.

Otherwise there is a way to run android images on "Oracle VM VirtualBox" but this way is not so easy, is hard to find a good android image and setup the envirnoment. [install Android in VirtualBox](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2015/03/how-to-install-android-5-0-lollipop-in-virtualbox-windows/#.Vj6PDoTAEUE)

ps. if you haven't done this already upgrade hd to an ssd , it helps a lot